# How to fire componentDidMount() or useEffect Hook on every visit to a page/screen?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

So I have an app with an activity. The app checks for Internet connection at the beginning. If there are no Internet connection, it will show a screen with a button to refresh the page. The problem is that my API calls (Axios) is located on `componentDidMount()` where it's called only once after the first render. Is there any way I can reload the page so it calls `componentDidMount` again?

I mean like total refresh. I am using EXPO btw. Any help is appreciated. Sorry there are no examples, I just wanted to get the idea if possible

Answer (score 3):

You can force update the component.
Check this:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

It will re-render the component.

check this example:

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
        this.forceUpdateHandler = this.forceUpdateHandler.bind(this);
  };

  forceUpdateHandler(){
    this.forceUpdate();
  };

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          <button onClick= {this.forceUpdateHandler} >FORCE UPDATE</button>
            <h4>Random Number : { Math.random() }</h4>
          </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Using forceUpdate this way is an anti-pattern. If you read your link, you'll see it says: "Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only read from this.props and this.state in render()". When the state or props used in render() change, your component will automatically re-render.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest putting your API call in it's own function `fetchData` within your component. `fetchData` can also `setState` after a successful fetch which will cause a re-render and show the fresh data. If you want to fetch fresh data on componentDidMount and also on a button click, then create a `fetchData` function and call that from within componentDidMount, then for your button just set your onPress prop appropriately `onPress={this.fetchData}`

Answer (score 3):

try with this example and check this too [check this too](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/)

```
 componentDidMount() {
            this.props.navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
                // do something here
            });
        }
```

Comment: I tried to implement this function, it doesn't' seem to work

Comment: try with useFocusEffect

Answer (score 0):

Remember by calling setState function on your component, you can refresh it. if there's a button that's going to refresh the page, i would do this:

```
<Button  onPress={() => this.setState({dummy: 1})} />
```

calling setState will update your component no matter what you object you pass to it. I'm not sure if re-rendering page, calls `componentDidMount` function, so maybe you need to move your API calls to some funciton `func` and call this function in your `componentDidMount`, and also after each button press event. example:

```
componentDidMount() {
  apiCalls()
}

apiCalls() {
   .... // your code
   this.setState({dummy: 1})
}

render() {
  <View>
    ...
    <Button  onPress={this.apiCalls.bind(this)} />
    ...

  </View>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the `Functional component` and did the following. I
used a state as a dependency in `useEffect` and changed that state on button press.

```
const [internetCheck, setInternetCheck] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
  //code
}, [internetcheck]);

return(
  <Button title='Retry' onPress(() => setInternetCheck(internetCheck + 1)) />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the number of views to this question, a lot of people are redirected here, like I was. So, my answer might not be relatable but it surely will help someone.

To re-render a screen I used `useIsFocused` hook from `@react-navigation/native`

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isFocused){
        console.log("Assi Gai Badal");
        //Update the state, it will cause a re-render
    }
}, [isFocused]);
```

It can be used in a class based component by using the `withNavigationFocus` higher-order component. This HOC wraps the desired Component class and passes the isFocused prop to it.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply refresh a React Native or Expo app by doing the following in a functional component.

**Step 1**

```
const [refreshPage, setRefreshPage] = useState("");
```

**Step 2**
Then use it in whatever component you want to use and refresh the page, e.g in alert

```
                Alert.alert(
                    "End of News",
                  "You have read all latest news for today ",
                  [
                    {
                      text: "Refresh Page",
                      onPress: () => {
                        setRefreshPage("refresh");
                        
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                  { cancelable: false }
                );
```

It will bring alert, when the user clicks refresh page button, the page will be refreshed.

Answer (score -1):

I was also stuck in the same problem then i figured it out that you just need Hooks or useState to resolve the refresh issue. In my case of refreshing random deck

```
    const [random1, setRandom1] = useState(
    Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length) + 1
    );

    <Image source={deck[random1]} style={styles.img} />

    <Button
    title="Refresh?"
    onPress={() => {
      setRandom1(Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length) + 1);
    }} />
```

I hope this might be helpful.