# React Native - Why Component inside TabNavigator Not get Called again

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

i stuck on one problem in react native and not yet get any solution of it.
I use TabNavigator. When i click on one tab, it will call the component inside it successfully. But when i leave the component by leave to another tab, then go back to previous tab, the data still persist / exist. It not get re-rendered at all. 
How to reload the component inside TabNavigator? I try using redux and implement componentDidUpdate inside the component class but it not called at all, seems that is not the issue. It just the component class not called second times
Please help.

My TabNavigator Code :

```
const AppTabNav = TabNavigator({
Home: {
    screen: AppStack,
    navigationOptions: {
        fontSize: 4,
    }
},
Notification: {
    screen: RequestStack,
    navigationOptions: {
        // headerTitle: 'HRIS',
        // label: 'HRIS',
        fontSize: 4
    }
},
Request222: {
    screen: NotifStack,
    navigationOptions: {
        headerTitle: 'HRIS',
        label: 'HRIS',
        fontSize: 4
    }
},},

{
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    animationEnabled: true,
    swipeEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#022846',
        // inactiveBackgroundColor: '#89898b',
        inactiveTintColor: '#89898b',
        upperCaseLabel: false,
        // activeBackgroundColor:'#fff',
        showLabel: true,
        showIcon: true,
        // style: styles.tabBar,
        style: {
            backgroundColor: '#eaeaec'
        },
    },     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how tabnavigator works. In fact, by default, all of your tabs are getting rendered in the inital load.

For component reload, this might help. ([React Native reload page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368728/react-native-reload-page))

Answer (score 0):

Screens in `TabNavigator` will only be rendered once unless any props or state values changed for the screen. This is the default and expected behavior.

If you need to re-render a screen when you revisit you can use [`addListener`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) to listen a focus event and change the required values for that screen accordingly (***example***: do a `fetch` to get data from server)

> **addListener** - *Subscribe to updates to navigation lifecycle*
>
> React Navigation emits events to screen components that subscribe to them:
>
> - `willBlur` - the screen will be unfocused
> - `willFocus` - the screen will focus
> - `didFocus` - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
> - `didBlur` - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)

*Example from docs*

```
const didBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
  'didBlur',
  payload => {
    console.debug('didBlur', payload);
  }
);

// Remove the listener when you are done
didBlurSubscription.remove();

// Payload

{
  action: { type: 'Navigation/COMPLETE_TRANSITION', key: 'StackRouterRoot' },
  context: 'id-1518521010538-2:Navigation/COMPLETE_TRANSITION_Root',
  lastState: undefined,
  state: undefined,
  type: 'didBlur',
};
```