# How to reload current page programmatically in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

My native app support multi-language functionality like 'English' and 'Danish'. For this I have created a drop down on top of the header with two menu options, for example if click on Danish language,it will set the 'Danish' language, but the effect is not displayed, for this I have to click on current menu, then the effect of the language is seen.
So my questions is how to reload current page in react native programmatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368728/react-native-reload-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try storing your locale in Redux and then update the UI from that state using container components.

Comment: Can you send sample demo link,so from that reference,i will achieve this functionality,Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can look at Spencer Carli's excellent React Native Currency Converter course - it's a free video course that covers both Redux and localization (or themes but you could do the same with localization that he does with themes - both are massive UI updates in response to a single action).  See https://learn.handlebarlabs.com/p/react-native-basics-build-a-currency-converter .  See also the redux docs at https://redux.js.org/ .  Hope that helps!  :-)

Comment: You're welcome.  An upvote would be appreciated!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is reloading. You must change the state on click, but believe me do not write custom localization. Here is the great plugin to do it https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization

Comment: Hi sir,Thanks for replay, but i have used this 'react-native-i18n' api it working fine for me,but my question is about how to do 'window.location.reload' in react-native app.

Comment: Maybe you need this https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate but if you need window.location.reload, then believe me you are on wrong way in react

Comment: Thank you for replay,this will be helpful for me.

Comment: can you tell should this method update other component data.In my situation there will be three component like header body and footer,if have change the state of variable in header component should this reflect on other body  and footer component.?

Comment: Do you use redux? If you want to update something in footer when you click something in header then you need global store. And one of the best option is redux. I advice you to use redux in every project if you don't want to suffer yourself

Comment: No sir i will not use redux in a project can you send me link related 'redux' that will help me for project.Thanks for replay.

Comment: Here is official react redux github page: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux and here is a great post to start using it https://medium.com/@mosesesan/tutorial-react-native-redux-boilerplate-4899f5c4f431

Comment: Thank you sir this will helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to cause a render of a page is by calling `this.setState()`. This will trigger the React lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need reload current page if you only need to change language, You can achive that with this library https://github.com/derniercri/react-native-redux-i18n