# how can i reload the page after deleting in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

this is my code to reject a profile to delete them
how can I reload the page automatically after deleting it?

```
const canceller = (item) => {
        firebase.firestore()
        .collection("ServiceProvider")
        .doc(item)
        .delete()
        .then(()=>{
           
          
           alert(`you have deleted the profile successfully  `);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [React Native reload page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47368728/5743988)

Answer (score 0):

You can call a `state` variable in your `.then()` method to cause your page to reload.

You can also use firebase's `onSnapshot()` methods, but this depends on how/if you're rending data from your `ServiceProvider` collection.